# Is this an infinite response or a finite response?

Tags: discrete-signals, infinite-impulse-response, finite-impulse-response

If you're given $h[n] = 1$ for every even number of $n$, otherwise it'll be 0. Is that considered an infinite response or a finite response and how do you know?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by (in)finite response.

Comment: This boils down to the question "how many even numbers are there?" I guess the answer should be obvious; am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

A finite impulse response (FIR) filter has an impulse response of finite length. It can be implemented by a non-recursive structure, but there are also cases where the designer would choose a recursive structure for implementing an FIR filter (e.g., a recursively implemented moving average filter, as explained in [this answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/24978/4298)).

An infinite impulse response (IIR) filter has an impulse response of infinite extension. Consequently, it cannot be implemented by a non-recursive structure, but it requires a recursive structure.

With the above explanation in mind, I think it should be straightforward to decide which class the system in your question belongs to.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, an answer seems obvious. Let me try a proof.

A filter with impulse response $h[n]$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ is FIR if there exist integers $P$ and $Q$ such that its response is zero for indices lower than $P$, and is zero for indices higher than $Q$:

- $\forall k <P$, $h[k] = 0$,
- $\forall k >Q$, $h[k] = 0$.

We will use contraposition: assuming the false to prove the true.

Suppose that your filter is FIR, then such a $Q$ exist. By standard inequalities, we will find an even number that contradicts some assumption: $Q \le |Q| < |Q|+1 < 2(|Q|+1)$.

By definition, $h[2(|Q|+1)] = 1$, which contradicts $\forall k >Q$, $h[k] = 0$. Hence, the hypothesis that $h$ is a FIR is false.

Comment: Sometimes, proving the obvious takes us back to the basics